# Is a group complement of a subspace of a vector space necessarily a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $W$ be a vector space. Let $U$ be a *subspace* and $V$ be a *subgroup* of $W$, and assume that $W$ is the direct sum (as groups!) of $U$ and $V$. Does it follow that $V$ is a subspace, such that in fact $W=U\oplus V$ as vector spaces? (In case a counterexample is found, i'd like to see if the answer is the same for finite and infinite dimensional vector spaces?)

Put another way, if $U$ and $V$ are complementary subgroups and $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication, does it follow that $V$ is also closed under scalar multiplication?

I can't see a particular reason why this should be the case, but at the same time I can't seem to find a counterexample, so here we are.... As a related example, considering $\Bbb C$ as a complex vector space, we have $\Bbb C = \Bbb R \oplus i\Bbb R$ as groups, but neither of these subgroups are subspaces, so it's not applicable.

Comment: In C^2 pick a complex subspace of dimension 1, now view everything over the reals and find a complement to that subspace (as a real subspace) which is not a complex subspace.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Post as an answer? Can you do the same over a field with $p^2$ elements?

Comment: You can. Suppose that K / F is an extension of finite fields, let V be a fin.dim. K-vector space, and let W be a K-subspace of V. Count the number of K-linear complements to W in V, and the number of F-linear complements: there are more of the latter.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! That was embarrassingly simple - I even thought about $\Bbb C^2$, but I guess four dimensions were two much for my little head haha. I'm happy to consider this question closed :)

Comment: @Milten, write an answer with the details.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sure, I can do that when I have a bit of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do things the proper way, let me flesh out the solution in the comments as an answer.

The idea suggested is to consider a field extension $K/F$ and a vector space $W$ over $K$ (which thereby also can be viewed as a vector space over $F$). Then choose $U$ as a $K$-linear subspace and $V$ as an $F$-linear complement. In general (probably always?), there are many choices for $V$ that are not $K$-linear, which means we get a solution to the problem.

Concrete example: Take $W=\Bbb C^2$, $U=\{(z,0)\mid z\in\Bbb C\}$, $V=\{(\alpha, \alpha+i\beta)\mid \alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R\}$.